# Can we send parameter to .properties file in java android?

Tags: java, android

properties file in assets folder I just want to know can I send parameter to these files? if yes can anyone show me how? here is the sample of my config.properties

`myquery.query=SELECT * FROM data WHERE typ='any' AND myName=` 'here i need to get parameter from java file'

Comment: What do you mean by sending parameters to files?

Comment: i just wrote queries in db.proeprties so i want to send parameter over there

Comment: you should put `?` in place of your parameters then after you read the query from file you can pass them to the methods that bind parameters to query strings.